# How to get req.route.path in express middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get the path(/entity/:view/:ver/) in the express middleware.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did not get anything that gives the result as expected. I tried using req.route.path in the middleware but its undefined

Comment: What about [`req.path`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path)?

Comment: No req.path is different than req.route.path

Answer (score 0):

The express `req` exposes [`originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl), [`baseUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl),  and [`path`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path). Log them and see which one correspond to what you are  looking for:

```js
const middelware = (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  console.log(req.baseUrl);
  console.log(req.path);
}
```

Click on the links to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

`req.route` is only present after express handles the request.
You can either access it in route-specific middleware, or if you need to access it globally and don't mind only having it after the request has been processed, you can wrap your code in `res.on('finish'...`

Example:

```
const loggingContextMiddleware: RequestHandler = (req, res, next) => {
  res.on('finish', () => {
    req.route // Is now present, and should contain what you need.
  });
  return next();
};
```

Comment: I tried using this but I find that req.route is still sometimes undefined. Not sure what causes it, but it does seem to sometimes happen with errors (not always though)

Comment: Actually I tried using app.all to add the middleware, and now req.route is always defined